# How do I add like in where

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I need to use like in where condition in stored procedure sql server.

I tried below code but showing error on `@product_name_id`.

where I made mistake ...can anyone help me

```
@product_name_id varchar(50)

as 
begin 
select Product_Name as [Product Name], Product_Id as [Product Id] from  
    tb_new_product_Name_id  where  Product_Name LIKE %@product_name_id% or Product_Id 
    like %@product_name_id%

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `''` around it:

```
...
where Product_Name LIKE '%' + @product_name_id + '%' 
   or Product_Id   LIKE '%' + @product_name_id + '%';
```

Answer (score 3):

try below: add '' for string in SQL

```
select Product_Name as [Product Name], Product_Id as [Product Id] from  
tb_new_product_Name_id  where  Product_Name LIKE '%'+@product_name_id+'%' or Product_Id 
like '%'+@product_name_id+'%'
```

Comment: This is not going to work because you stuck `@product_name_id` into string.

Comment: @Happy i don't think it gives u error.because for the like operator we use select name from Person where name like '%Vaibh%' so I concatenate string.